# Java Spring Boot - api object creation

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on a Java Spring boot api.

when the the call is made to get /api/home

I want to return this json sample structure.

```
      var response = [
            {
              "type": "profile-breakdown",
              "order": 0,
              "grid-width": 6,
              "grid-background": "",
              "grid-background-url": "",
              "title": "",
              "contents": {
                "name": "Name1",
                "avatar" : 1,
                "nextSDQ": 4,
                "SQDCount": 3
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "current-standing",
              "order": 1,
              "grid-width": 6,
              "grid-background": "",
              "grid-background-url": "",
              "title": "Your current standing summary",
              "contents": {
                "0": ["emotional distress", "behavioural difficulties", "hyperactivity and concentration difficulties", "difficulties in getting along with other young people"],
                "4": ["kind and helpful behaviour"]
              }
            }
]
```

--
I've been building the various functions to get "profile-breakdown" and "current-standing" -- I want to append the responses to these to mimic the above structure.

so in MyService where /api/home gets RequestMapped to I begin to hook into my class MyApiHome

```
    MyApiHome myApiHome = new MyApiHome();
    JSONObject homeObj = myApiHome.getHomeData();
```

in MyApiHome -- I want to make "homeObj" in getHomeData an array as opposed to an JSONOBject - but then I start to fall into trouble with casts etc.. I want to build this in such a way - that if getProfileBreakDown is null or decoupled it isn't appended to the homeObj.

```
public class MyApiHome {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public JSONObject getHomeData(){
        //build clean home object
        JSONObject homeObj = new JSONObject();              
        homeObj.put("profile", this.getProfileBreakDown());
        homeObj.put("currentstanding", this.getCurrentStanding());
        //HashMap<List<String>, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<List<String>, Object>();
                //hashMap.put())


        return homeObj;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Object getProfileBreakDown(){
        //build clean home object
        JSONObject contents = new JSONObject();     
        contents.put("name", "Name1");
        contents.put("avatar", 1);
        contents.put("nextSDQ", 4);
        contents.put("SQDCount", 3);

        //build clean home object
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();             
        json.put("type", "profile-breakdown");
        json.put("order", 0);
        json.put("grid-width", 6);
        json.put("grid-background", "");
        json.put("grid-background-url", "");
        json.put("title", "");
        json.put("contents", contents);

        return json;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Object getCurrentStanding(){

        String[] stressArray1 = {"emotional distress", "behavioural difficulties", "hyperactivity and concentration difficulties", "difficulties in getting along with other young people"};
        String[] stressArray2 = {"kind and helpful behaviour"};


        //build clean home object
        JSONObject contents = new JSONObject();     
        contents.put("0", stressArray1);
        contents.put("4", stressArray2);

        //build clean home object
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();             
        json.put("type", "current-standing");
        json.put("order", 1);
        json.put("grid-width", 6);
        json.put("grid-background", "");
        json.put("grid-background-url", "");
        json.put("title", "Your current standing summary");
        json.put("contents", contents);

        return json;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you need to check for null, then check before adding to homeObj.

Comment: @CS_noob - sure --  my main question is - instead of homeObj.put("profile", getProfBre) -- I just want to stack the various responses so if(getProfBre){home[getProfBre]}  -- stack it as an array with objects

Comment: Please check about JSONArray.

Comment: What I mean is -- when I start to touch the code -- it goes back up the parents -- let me try that though. I was starting to make a mess.

Comment: Good solutions it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an array of JSONs, we need to use JSONArray object which has a list of JSONObjects.

Answer (score 0):

So using JSONArray.

I add to a json blob like a data stack.

```
JSONArray homeObj = new JSONArray();
    if(this.getProfileBreakDown() != null){
        homeObj.add(this.getProfileBreakDown());
    }
    if(this.getCurrentStanding() != null){
        homeObj.add(this.getCurrentStanding());
    }
```